How to Display Page Numbers in Android Paging 3?
I’m currently developing an app using Android Paging 3 for web communication. In the PagingSource, I noticed that page numbers are incremented or decremented using the key. I would like to display the current page number in the view. Is there any method or API available to achieve this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
